# Flask Socketio not updating data

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am working with Flask Socketio. My code right now console logs every time a user opens a page. However when I open the page in a new tab/window the console of the original user in not updated. Below is the code, have a look at it

```
  let socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
socket.on("connect",() => {
    socket.emit("my custom event",{text:"I have joined"})
  })
  socket.on("my response",function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
  })
```

And here is the python code for flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "hope"
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/1')
def random_route():
    return render_template("index2.html")


@socketio.on('message')
def message(data):
    print(data)


@socketio.on('my custom event')
def handle_custom_event(data):
    emit("my response", data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default for the `emit` function is to address the event only to the sender. If you want to address all your connected clients, you have to indicate so with the `broadcast` option:

```py
@socketio.on('my custom event')
def handle_custom_event(data):
    emit("my response", data, broadcast=True)
```